# What is the Need of Template Engine in nodejs Application

Tags: node.js

I want to know about that what is need of templates like.. jade , ejs in nodejs web application. If I don't use it and use directly html then what difficulty I would face ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to repeat each of pattern each time in each page you will want to return to user. So it's just for your "time profit". Almost all pages in future will need to be changed. So if you will make it in "directly html" you will have so much pain to make one little change on each page.